# Session Experies and Get Logged Out Within Few Minutes

Tags: login, session, logout

I have wordpress simple blog with few plugins installed. My problem is that after logging and working for few minutes (hardly 2-5 minutes), session expires and I get logged out of the admin area.

This generally happens when I visit front-end part of the website while I am logged in. If I keep clicking on different section of admin area, It will **not** log me out.

I have `WP Fastest Cache`, `Autoptimize`, `PWA` and other few plugins. I have also changed the login url for security reason. This could be the reason? 
Also I am using cloudflare (free plan) but I am not using their caching.

**Note:** I have already checked my domain name setting and it is correct.
Also, there is other WordPress website on my server and they have no such problem

Answer (score 0):

This can have many causes. In my case right now it had been a no longer maintained plugin that became incompatible with WordPress after an update of WordPress itself. (Just in case it's relevant, the plugin was [WP Login Timeout Settings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-login-timeout-settings/).)

To test if this is the cause I propose that you disable all plugins and see if it solves the issue. If the session expiry happens so fast that you can't do it in the WordPress user interface, there are [other ways to disable WordPress plugins](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wordpress-plugins/).